# How to use explode function to delimit and display different values

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, explode

I’m making a random sentence generator for my English class. I’m close but because of my limited php and javascript knowledge I need to ask for help. I’m not bad at reading the code, I just get stuck writing it.

I want to use explode to break up a string of comma seperated values. The string is a mix of English and Spanish, on the .txt file they would seperated like:

```
The book, El libro
The man, El hombre
The woman, La mujer
```

etc.

I would like to break these two values into an array and display them in separate places on my web page.
I`m going to use a random text generator script that I found, it’s working great with no problems. I just need to modify it using explode to read, separate the values into an array, and be able to display the separate values of the array.

```
<?php

/* File, where the random text/quotes are stored one per line */
$settings['text_from_file'] = 'quotes.txt';

/*
How to display the text?
0 = raw mode: print the text as it is, when using RanTex as an include
1 = Javascript mode: when using Javascript to display the quote
*/
$settings['display_type'] = 1;

/* Allow on-the-fly settings override? 0 = NO, 1 = YES */
$settings['allow_otf'] = 1;

// Override type?
if ($settings['allow_otf'] && isset($_GET['type']))
{
$type = intval($_GET['type']);
}
else
{
$type = $settings['display_type'];
}

 // Get a list of all text options
if ($settings['text_from_file'])
{
$settings['quotes'] = file($settings['text_from_file']);
}

// If we have any text choose a random one, otherwise show 'No text to                              choose from'
if (count($settings['quotes']))
{
$txt = $settings['quotes'][array_rand($settings['quotes'])];
}
else
{
$txt = 'No text to choose from';
 }

// Output the image according to the selected type
if ($type)
{
// New lines will break Javascript, remove any and replace them with <br />
$txt = nl2br(trim($txt));
$txt = str_replace(array("\n","\r"),'',$txt);

// Set the correct MIME type
header("Content-type: text/javascript");

// Print the Javascript code
echo 'document.write(\''.addslashes($txt).'\')';
}
else
{
echo $txt;
}
?>
```

The script that displays the result:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="rantex.php?type=1"></script>
```

Can someone please help me modify the rantex.php file so that I can use explode to separate the different comma separated values, and use a different script to call them in different places on my web page?

Thank you, and please excuse my noobness.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems unnecessary, since file() will have already removed new line characters:

```
// New lines will break Javascript, remove any and replace them with <br />
$txt = nl2br(trim($txt));
$txt = str_replace(array("\n","\r"),'',$txt);
```

To break your line, you may instead use:

```
list($english, $spanish) = explode(', ', trim($txt));
```

Comment: I hope I'm reading the code right. If this splits the
    $txt
value into
    $english
    $spanish
values, how can I separate them with different JavaScripts? 
I know I can use the stock
     <script type="text/javascript" src="rantex.php?type=1"></script>
but no for two different placements on my web page. Thanks

Comment: Durning testing using your approach I was able to call the $english value but not the $spanish value. I tried using this: 
 echo 'document.write(\''.addslashes($english).'\')';
 echo 'document.write(\''.addslashes($spanish).'\')';
}
else
{
 echo $txt;
} That's a bit not right, right?

Comment: The script supposes that each line is separated by a comma followed by a space.

Comment: Not clear what you want to achieve by calling twice the script. If you want to write to two different places in the HTML, try using:echo 'document.getElementById('id1').innerHtml = \''+addslashes($english)+'\'

Comment: Yeah I saw the extra space later but I am still jammed up. Yea no I don't want to call on it twice but I do need to somehow do the logic on a .PHP and call the $english and $spanish variables separately with some JavaScript on a static HTML page.Thanks for your help

Comment: EDIT ok, using your method I have successfully been able to get the two variables, now how do I call them up individually on my HTML page?

Comment: You could store the values in javascript variables and use them later in your page (your script will need to be loaded only once in the head)

Comment: Or you could use document.getElementById('id1').innerHtml = ... to change the contant of a HTML element, but then the script must be executed after loading the page.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to use PHP to serve a static page with some random sentences, right? So why not use PHP to serve valid JSON, and handle to display logic on the client?

Heres a quick implementation.

```
// Get the data from the text file
$source = file_get_contents('./quotes.txt', true);

// Build an array (break on every line break)                           
$sentences = explode("\n", $source);

// Filter out empty values (if there is any)
$filtered = array_filter($sentences, function($item) { 
  return $item !== "";
});

// Build a hashmap of the array
$pairs = array_map(function($item) { 
  return ['sentence' => $item];
}, $filtered);

// Encode the hashmap to JSON, and return this to the client.
$json = json_encode($pairs);
```

Now you can let the client handle the rest, with some basic JavaScript.

```
// Return a random sentence from your list.
var random = sentences[Math.floor(Math.random() * sentences.length)];

// Finally display it
random.sentence
```

[edit]

You can get the JSON data to client in many ways, but if you don't want to use something like Ajax, you could simply just dump the contents on your webpage, then use JavaScript to update the random sentence, from the global window object.

```
// Inside your php page

<p>English: <span id="english"></span></p>
<p>Spanish: <span id="spanish"></span></p>

<script>

  var sentences = <?= json_encode($pairs); ?>;
  var random = sentences[Math.floor(Math.random() * sentences.length)];

  var elspa = document.getElementById('spanish');
  var eleng = document.getElementById('english');

  elspa.innerText = random.sentence.split(',')[1];
  eleng.innerText = random.sentence.split(',')[0];

</script>
```

Comment: The random generator I'm using does use PHP to process the logic and I can use either JavaScript or PHP on my static web page. I am interested in trying out the method you suggest, though I`m not sure how to implement it. I hate asking to be hand-held but can you suggest please how I can call these values to my web page? Thanks for your attention

Comment: Well, its quite hard not knowing the rest of your setup, but basically just get a hold of the path where the .txt file is, and use the above methods to parse the file.

If you are using vanilla PHP and HTML mixed you could just echo the result in your page and grab it with JavaScript from the window object. If you have some kind of MVC setup you could return the JSON from your controller, and even get the JSON content via an AJAX call.

Comment: Yes sorry, I am using DW CS6 and the latest MAMP for testing. When the site is ready I will get the appropriate hosting to handle my needs, so I'm open to the best format. The method you suggest seems much more efficient than the script I found online, I can read it and see where it's going but I`m not sure what the JavaScript on my web page would look like. It's currently using   <script type="text/javascript" src="rantex.php?type=1"></script>  for the one value. Thank you.

Comment: Edited my answer. Ill hope it will help.

Comment: Yes, it's helping a lot thanks. I think there is a misunderstanding and it's my fault for not seeing it sooner. Yes I do want to generate random sentences but I need more control. When I generate some random words I need to have their Spanish meanings connected to that I can display it under the English words. The plan is to have a text file with a list of two values separated with a comma: The book,El libro etc. The randomness
is needed to get the given random line but I need to parse them at the comma so I have an english value and a spanish value that i can display separately. Thanks again

Comment: Ug, I am not having luck with this. DW is giving me error comments on -- $pairs = array_map(function($item) { 
  return ['sentence' => $item];
}, $filtered);  --- I apologize for my noobness, I will keep up my trial and error and I think I can figure this out

Comment: Whats the error message? Have you checked that the .txt file is successfully loaded by PHP?

Comment: The error message is just that there is an error that can't helped with code hinting. The txt file is good because its loading up my old PHP thats connected to it. Above you provided 3 bits of code, the first 2 go my PHP page to sort out the .txt file and the last bit is for my static page, yes? I do appreciate your help

Comment: You should get an error message from PHP, not DW. The error message should be visible when you visit the page with your browser. If you dont see any messages your should turn on error reporting. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Oh, maybe you are using a old PHP version? Then you cant use the new array syntax, change the array_map function return to:

array("sentence" => $item);

Comment: i have been reading up on json and ajax and see that is the way to go, instead of having a text file as source I want tobuild it on the .PHP, create the array, encode to json, and call it to my .html. I do not know where I should randomize and explode yet. I am doing a lot of trial and error with only errors. I`m trying a lot of examples online with the help of your solution. I think I am close tho  EDIT  going to check out the correction you suggested

Comment: Yes, that seems to have been the problem. Your code looks so good but it just doesnt function for me, I know its my fault. I am just stuck, I know it is because of the many ways to do this, and I am starting to confuse and mix things up badly. I just want a .php to do my random logic, get an array mixed with spanish and english to be split, and javascript the two different spanish and english words in two separate places on my .html. I know it is cake for the experienced, for me it is just fatal.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I have this figured out, I take 0 credit because I paid someone to do it. Special thanks to @stormpat for sending me in the right direction, if not for him I wouldn't have looked at this from a JSON point of view.

The .PHP file is like so:

```
<?php
$f_contents = file('quotes.txt'); 
$line = trim($f_contents[rand(0, count($f_contents) - 1)]);
$data = explode(',', $line);
$data['eng'] = $data[0];
$data['esp'] = $data[1];

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

On the .HTML page in the header:

```
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    (function ($) {
        $(function()
        {
            function load_random_data() {
                $.get('random_line.php', function(data) {
                    var data = $.parseJSON(data);
                    $('#random_english').text(data.eng);
                    $('#random_spanish').text(data.esp);
                });
            }
            load_random_data();
            $('#get_random').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                load_random_data();
            });


        });
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

This splits the different variables into classes, so to call them into my html page I call them by their class, for instance I wanted to drop the variable into a table cell so I gave the individual td cell a class:

```
                <td id="random_spanish"></td>
                <td id="random_english"></td>
```

Plus as a bonus the coder threw in a nifty button to refresh the json classes:

```
<input type="button" value="Get random" id="get_random" />
```

So now I don`t have to have my students refresh the whole web page, they can just hit the button and refresh the random variables.

Thanks again everyone!